# How do I escape an apostrophy in liquid? (Business Catalyst)

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

Im needing to call a json item with an apostrophy in it.

```html
{% for item in search.items -%}
<a href="{{item.url}}">Position: {{item.['Position Title']}}</a><br>

<ul>
  <li><strong>State:</strong> {{item.['Vacancy State']}}</li>
  <li><strong>Numbers Required:</strong> {{item.["Numbers Req\'d Min"]}} - {{item.["Numbers Req\'d Max"]}}</li>
  <li><strong>Employer:</strong> {{item.['Employer Name']}}</li>
</ul>

<p><strong>Description</strong></p>
<div>{{item.description}}</div>

<ul>
  <li><strong>Listed Date:</strong> {{item.releaseDate | date}}</li>
  <li><strong>Expiry Date:</strong> {{item.expiryDate | date}}</li>
</ul>

{% endfor -%}
```

The `{{item.["Numbers Req\'d Min"]}}` - `{{item.["Numbers Req\'d Max"]}}</li>` section is not working as there is an apostrophe in the web app item. -> `Req'd`

Does any one know how I can successfully call this in Business Catalyst? I tried a `\` but that is not working currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the code without escaping it.

Try: `{{item.["Numbers Req'd Min"]}}`

Since it is enclosed in `" "` it should work. When you escape the `'` it sees the `\` as a character and doesn't render correctly.